# driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.BACK); -error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, android-emulator, appium

[Check the code here - I Got this below error- need solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxhLO.png)

I'm writing java code in eclipse and through appium tool I'm runing the java code in Android emulator. And I'm using selenium-java:3.141.59, java-client:7.0.0 and testng:7.4.0

Check my code in the above link or "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxhLO.png"

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Copy and paste them into your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.